# Java multiple class calculator not working. Cant pass variables between classes. Won't output the answer

Tags: java, calculator

I have created 2 different classes inside the package called multiclasscalculator.

The first class takes the input and transfers the values to the other class which then calculates the answer.

```
 package multiclasscalculator;
import java.util.*;
import multiclasscalculator.Math;
/**
 *
 * @author student
 */
public class MultiClassCalculator {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double number1;
        double number2;
        String opperation;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Math my = new Math();

        System.out.println("Enter a Number");
        number1 = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter another Number");
        number2 = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter an opperation");
        opperation = sc.next();       
    }   
}
```

The class that evaluates the math part is:

```
 package multiclasscalculator;
import multiclasscalculator.MultiClassCalculator;
/**
 *
 * @author student
 */
public class Math {

    public static double math(double number1, double number2, String opperation){
        MultiClassCalculator hi = new MultiClassCalculator();


        if (opperation.equals("add")){

            double answer = number1 + number2;
            System.out.print("The answer is " + answer);

        } else if (opperation.equals("minus")){

            double answer = number1 - number2;
            System.out.print("The answer is " + answer);

        } else if (opperation.equals("multiply")){

            double answer = number1 * number2;
            System.out.print("The answer is " + answer);

        } else if (opperation.equals("divide")){

            double answer = number1 / number2;
            System.out.print("The answer is " + answer);

        }
    return 0;    
    }
```

When I input numbers and the opperation in it doesn't give me the answer it just says opperation completed.

Comment: How do you expect it to give you an output if you don't call it from the main?

Answer (score 1):

You need call the caculation method in the `main` method of `MultiClassCalculator`:

```
Math.math(number1, number2, opperation);
```

And, since `Math.math` is static, you need not create an instance `Math my = new Math();`.